# Obtaining metadata from magnetlink infohash

Tags: python, bittorrent, magnet-uri

I am learning about bittorrent protocols and have a question I'm not too sure about.

According to [BEP009](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0009.html),

> **magnet URI format**
>
> The magnet URI format is:
>
> v1: magnet:?xt=urn:btih:info-hash&dn=name&tr=tracker-url
>
> v2: magnet:?xt=urn:btmh:tagged-info-hash&dn=name&tr=tracker-url
>
> **info-hash** Is the info-hash hex encoded, for a total of 40 characters. For compatability with existing links in the wild, clients should also support the 32 character base32 encoded info-hash.
>
> **tagged-info-hash** Is the multihash formatted, hex encoded full infohash for torrents in the new metadata format. 'btmh' and 'btih' exact topics may exist in the same magnet if they describe the same hybrid torrent.

example magnet link: `magnet:?xt=urn:btih:407AEA6F3D7DC846879449B24CA3F57DB280DE5C&dn=ubuntu-educationpack_14+04_all&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexplodie.org%3A6969`

Correct me if i'm wrong, but `urn:btih:407AEA6F3D7DC846879449B24CA3F57DB280DE5C` is the `info-hash` from the magnet link, and i will need to decode it to be able to obtain a `bencoded` metadata such as listed in [BEP015](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0015.html). Things such as: `downloaded, left, uploaded, event, etc.`

My question is, how do I decode this in python?

Answer (score 0):

The info-hash in Magnet Link is the same as the info-hash required for a UDP Tracker (20-bytes SHA-1 hash of bencoded "info" dictionary of a torrent).

Additionally, a UDP Tracker doesn't use bencoded data at all, just bytes!
Bencoded format is used by HTTP/HTTPs trackers though.

Comment: Hello, thanks for that! Meaning to say, magnet link's info-hash skips the bencoding part that would have been needed for a .tor file right? How do I then go about `announcing` it to the udp trackers to return me the peer lists? Because according to BEP015. The payload should have these information - such as: downloaded, left, uploaded, event, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can search some open source code like [libtorrent](https://www.libtorrent.org/reference-Bencoding.html#overview). It's written by C++, so you need to read the bdecode and bencode part. That part is not complex, and then you can write python codes by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> Correct me if i'm wrong, but
> urn:btih:407AEA6F3D7DC846879449B24CA3F57DB280DE5C is the info-hash
> from the magnet link, and i will need to decode it to be able to
> obtain a bencoded metadata such as listed in BEP015. Things such as:
> downloaded, left, uploaded, event, etc.

Infohash is a unique SHA1 hash that identifies a torrent. Therefore it cannot be further decoded to obtain any further information, it's just an identifier. Furthermore, if you think about it, the link would constantly need to change if it contained this information.

You must use this infohash in the announce request to a tracker. The purpose of the announce request is to let the tracker know that you are downloading the particular hash, how far along you are and to provide you with peers the tracker knows about.

In your example there are two UDP trackers:

```
tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexplodie.org%3A6969
```

After URL decoding these, they become:

```
tr=udp://tracker.opentrackr.org:1337/announce&tr=udp://explodie.org:6969
```

So, these are the trackers you must send your announce request to by implementing https://libtorrent.org/udp_tracker_protocol.html

Note that does not give you any information about the torrent file, for that you need to implement BEP-9.